# Django model DateTimeField set auto_now_add format or modify the serializer

Tags: python, django, datetime, serialization, python-datetime

I have this field in my model:

```
createdTime = models.DateTimeField(_('Creation date'), help_text=_('Date of the creation'),
                                   auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

And it is saved with this format:

> 2016-05-18T15:37:36.993048Z

So I would like to convert it to this format `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:S')` but I dont know where to do it.

I have a simple serializer class, could I override it to modify the format? or maybe create a get_date() model method?

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for object.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Object
```

My settings:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = False
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `DATETIME_FORMAT` in your `settings.py` as specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT).

> The default formatting to use for displaying datetime fields in **any**
>   part of the system. Note that if `USE_L10N` is set to True, then the
>   locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied
>   instead

The date part of your `settings.py` should afterwards look like so:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' 
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False # if you plan to disable timezone support
```

Alternatively, you can manually change formats after retrieval by doing:

```
import datetime

datetime_str = '2016-05-18T15:37:36.993048Z'
old_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
new_format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

new_datetime_str = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, old_format).strftime(new_format)
print(new_datetime_str)
#'18-05-2016 15:37:36'
```

This conversion can be added to your serializer or model as your proposed `get_date()` method

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I added these settings to my settings.py DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:S' and USE_L10N = True but it still is saving the date like this:
+----------------------------+
| createdTime                |
+----------------------------+
| 2016-05-18 15:37:36.993048 |
| 2016-05-23 08:25:41.536701 |
| 2016-05-23 08:27:24.348154 |
+----------------------------+
I also have USE_I18N = True

Comment: Your format is missing a character: `%S` not `S`. Then `USE_L10N = False`.

Comment: Thanks! Coffee hadnt kicked in yet... One question, I also have USE_I18N = True (different from USE_L10N), is that field also needed to be set to False?

Comment: `USE_I18N` only concerns the Django translation system. I don't think its value affects your `datetime` settings

Comment: mm it's weird then, I dont know why is still not working, I updated my question with the settings I am using in Django 1.9

Comment: Old values already in the DB may not come in the new format. In any case, I suggest you try the other approach of manually changing formats using a model method.

Comment: I tried adding new ones, They appear with the same format the older ones

Comment: Yes, I am modyfing them in the serializer, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

You can define the format of your DateTimeField in the serializer of the model
(checked on django 3.1.5):

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   createdTime = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

   class Meta:
      model = Object
      fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: This worked well for me. The `settings.py` configuration mentioned above seem to be outdated for the lastest Django.

Comment: Hello it works for me too. thanks
09 February 2022 08:18 pm --- how to put in this format ?
if u can help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in django templates if you want to format datetime in user's view:

```
product_import_date|date:"d/m/Y H:i:s"
```

You can follow this link to learn more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/